# At what level do monsters cast cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

A 9 HD Yuan-ti Pureblood can innately cast the *poison spray* cantrip 3 times per day. The monster description says the save is DC 12, but it does not go into damage. So does it do 1d12 or 2d12 damage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the *Monster Manual* (p. 10) under Special Traits, Innate Spellcasting:

> Unless noted otherwise, an innate spell of 1st level or higher is always cast at its lowest possible level and can't be cast at a higher level. **If a monster has a cantrip where its level matters and no level is given, use the monster's challenge rating.**

The damage for a Yuan-ti Pureblood's *Poison Spray* cantrip would be 1d12 since it is a CR 1 monster and no level is specified for the cantrip. *MM*, p. 310.